# Setting Width and Height of Fancybox using a form and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

I have a form

```
<form action="getData.php" method="POST" id="myForm">
<input type="input" size="20" name="myName" />
<input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Which passes the data to fancybox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#myForm").bind("submit", function() {

    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        width: "500",
        height: "500",
        cache       : false,
        url         : "getData.php",
        data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function(data) {
            $.fancybox(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
});


});
</script>
```

However i cant seem to be able to set the size or type of fancybox?

Comment: What is contained in the data variable in your success callback? And why are you passing width and height to $.ajax? I think you are getting a few things confused here.

Comment: The value of myName and anything else i have in getData.php.  Fancybox opens up getData.php and shows the value of myName as well as the other content in getData.php but width and height dont work. I want to be able to specify the height and width of the fancybox and possible set it as an iframe

Answer (score 2):

Boolean and integer values should be set without quotes.

So in order to set fancybox `type` as `iframe` with your specific dimensions (a 500x500px box) tweak your script like:

```
$("#myForm").bind("submit", function() {
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  url: "getData.php",
  data: $(this).serializeArray(),
  success: function(data) {
   $.fancybox(data,{
    'width': 500,
    'height': 500,
    'type': 'iframe',
    'autoScale': false
   }); // fancybox
  } // success
 }); // ajax
 return false;
}); // bind
```

Since the `width`, `height` and `type` are your fancybox settings, they should go inside the fancybox function, not in the *ajax* function.

Also notice that we set `autoScale` to `false` to make sure that you will get the size as in your `width/height` options.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    $.fancybox.resize();
```